# Why Xcode say it may leak?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I defined splitBarArr in .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *splitBarArr;
```

And I also set it nil in viewDidUnload, and released it in dealloc.

Why XCode still say that it's a potential memory leak?

Img here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LMMZ.png

Comment: Did you try running it via instruments? After rereading your question I realized that it might be the stupid static analyzer and my answer just works around that stupidity. Your code should be ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when assigning `retain` property the retain count increments by 1. Hence `alloc`ing array does `+1` and assigning it to property via `self` does `+1` again. The `release` in dealloc does `-1` so you still have `+1` left. Doing assigning like this will fix the problem:

```
self.splitBarArr = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: Thank you! This kicked the analyze info away.